# change color based on SQL table expression

Tags: ssrs-2008

I'm building a general report model, that can produce different reports, based on values from a SQL SERVER DB, in the same report model. For that I need to have astatic values or some formulas in a DB TABLE, that controls the color of the values.

Example:

```
select * from GIP_RPT_BAR_FORMATO_COLUNAS
where id_report = 5
and ambito = 'cor'
```

Query result:

```
ambito -> cor
id_report -> 5 num_quadro -> 1
id_mes -> NULL 
col1 -> Red
col2 -> Green col3-> Black
col4 -> iif (Fields!COL4.Value>0,"Green","Red")
```

and in the report I have a Dataset (DS_COR)that reads this query,but when I configure the color expression, doesn't work.

Example for color expression:

```
"set expression for color" 
=First(Fields!col4.Value, "DS_COR")
```

The report don't give any error, just ignores the color expression, which is if the value of column 4 > 0 then the color is green, otherwise, the color is red. The report shows all black.

Is there any way to put this formula to work?

Comment: You say you don't get any errors, but how about warnings? If your color expression results in a non-color value, you'll get a `[rsInvalidColor]` warning and the text color will default to Black.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
i'm working directly on report builder, and i don't get any warnings.
What i'm trying to do is the expression color result for the DS =First(Fields!col4.Value, "DS_COR") is the formula that i have in col4.value iif (Fields!COL4.Value>0,"Green","Red").
Is it possible ?